# Conditional BackgroundWorker Scenario

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a GUI which contains a list of test scripts in a listbox on the main form. I want to have the `BackgroundWorker` execute different scripts depending on what item was selected from the listbox.

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   if(listbox.SelectedItem.ToString() == test1)
   {
      testcase test1 = new testcase(); // instantiate the script
      test1.script1(); // run the code
   }
}
```

However, when I try to do this I get the `InvalidOperationException occurred` message since I am attempting a cross-thread operation. Is there another way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your data to the background thread before calling your background worker.

```
bw.RunWorkerAsync(listbox.SelectedItem.ToString());
...
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItem = (string)e.Argument;

    if(selectedItem == test)
    {
        testcase test1 = new testcase(); // instantiate the script
        test1.script1(); // run the code
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to read a value from a UI element from a different thread. 
This is not allowed. Hence you get the `InvalidOperationException`.

UI elements are owned by the main (UI) thread.

In order to access UI elements from a different thread, you need to invoke the current dispatcher:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItem = "";
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
    {
        selectedItem = listbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    if(selectedItem == test)
    {
        testcase test1 = new testcase(); // instantiate the script
        test1.script1(); // run the code
    }
}
```

Note that when you invoke the dispatcher, the threads synchronize to safely get the value cross-threaded. You don't wan't to invoke your complete code inside the dispatcher because then it wouldn't be executed on a different thread anymore

Comment: I can only get `this.Invoke`

Comment: @nevets are you on WPF or Winforms? the syntax is slightly different between the two. The concept is the same